# JQuery Steps - rename "Finish" Button to something else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery Steps with my MVC 5. Everything seem to be working right now.

The last button default "Finish". I want to know how to rename the "Finish" button to say something like "Create" or "Submit"?

I opened the jquery.steps.js file and found this code. I replaced the finish: "Finish" to finish: "Create" but this doesn't change anything.

```
labels: {
    /**
     * Label for the cancel button.
     *

     **/
    cancel: "Cancel",

    current: "current step:",

    /**

     **/
    pagination: "Pagination",

    /**
     * Label for the finish button.
     *
     * @property finish
     * @type String
     * @default "Finish"
     * @for defaults
     **/
    finish: "Finish",

    /**
     * Label for the next button.
     *
     * @property next
     * @type String
     * @default "Next"
     * @for defaults
     **/
    next: "Next",

    /**
     * Label for the previous button.
     *
     * @property previous
     * @type String
     * @default "Previous"
     * @for defaults
     **/
    previous: "Previous",

    /**
     * Label for the loading animation.
     *
     * @property loading
     * @type String
     * @default "Loading ..."
     * @for defaults
     **/
    loading: "Loading ..."
}
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code?

Comment: make sure your js file is not being cached . use private browser to check if you see the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this and found that the correct way to do this is

```
labels: {finish: "SUBMIT"},
```

Example

```
$(".wizard").steps({
        labels: {finish: "Make Payment"},
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "fieldset"
});
```

From the documentation
https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Settings

Answer (score 0):

Got it. To rename the Finish button to SUBMIT I opened and edited the jquery.steps.min.js file. Like this

```
finish:"SUBMIT"
```